# How do I get a link_to the destroy action of a nested controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

If I have the following nested route:

```
  resources :teams do
    resources :team_memberships
  end
```

How do I get a `link_to` destroy a specific team_membership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
<%= link_to "remove", team_team_membership_path(@team, @membership), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

Look at your `rake routes`